# How to solve the issue "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $"

Tags: java

I am getting "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $" when I am retrieve the list from database.How to fix this issue where I am mistaken in my code..thanks in advance.

Json response I am getting is below,

```
   [{
    "eventId":1,
    "ringeeUserId":2,
    "text":"Reception1",
    "place":"Erode",
    "eventDate":"2015-10-03",
    "startTime":"09:00 AM",
    "endTime":"12:00 PM",
    "isActive":0,
    "isDelete":0,
    "eventUserRelationBOs":[]
    }]
```

EventBO class file is below,

```
 package com.ringeeapp.service.businessobjects;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.List;

    public class EventBO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 281625146097131515L;

    private long eventId;

    private long ringeeUserId;

    private String text;

    private String place;

    private String eventDate;

    private String startTime;

    private String endTime;

    private int isActive;

    private int isDelete;

    private List<EventUserRelationBO> eventUserRelationBOs;

    public long getEventId() {
        return eventId;
    }

    public void setEventId(long eventId) {
        this.eventId = eventId;
    }

    public long getRingeeUserId() {
        return ringeeUserId;
    }

    public void setRingeeUserId(long ringeeUserId) {
        this.ringeeUserId = ringeeUserId;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getPlace() {
        return place;
    }

    public void setPlace(String place) {
        this.place = place;
    }

    public String getEventDate() {
        return eventDate;
    }

    public void setEventDate(String eventDate) {
        this.eventDate = eventDate;
    }

    public String getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(String startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public String getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    public void setEndTime(String endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

    public int getIsDelete() {
        return isDelete;
    }

    public void setIsDelete(int isDelete) {
        this.isDelete = isDelete;
    }

    public int getIsActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setIsActive(int isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

    public List<EventUserRelationBO> getEventUserRelationBOs() {
        return eventUserRelationBOs;
    }

    public void setEventUserRelationBOs(List<EventUserRelationBO> eventUserRelationBOs) {
        this.eventUserRelationBOs = eventUserRelationBOs;
    }

}
```

The below code that process json data

```
public @ResponseBody String getAllInvites(@RequestParam("userBO") String userBo) {
        List<EventBO> eventBOs = new ArrayList<EventBO>();
        UserBO userBO = gson.fromJson(userBo, UserBO.class);
        try {
            eventBOs = manageEventServiceImpl.getAllInvites(userBO);
            log.info("getting all events for user " + userBO.getRingeeUserId());
        } catch (UserServiceException serExp) {
            log.error("Error while getting event for userId id" + userBO.getRingeeUserId(), serExp);
        }
        return gson.toJson(eventBOs);
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing the JSON you did post here is not exactly the JSON you are trying to parse - Are you sure you made an exact copy?

Comment: yes it is an exact copy

Comment: Please show the code you use to process the JSON data.

Comment: can u please check my code now

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of EventBO, but trying to read as object. If you unmarshal like this:

```
EventBO bo = gson.fromJson(JSON, EventBO.class);
```

than you will receive error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $"

But if you change code to:

```
EventBO[] list = gson.fromJson(JSON, EventBO[].class);
```

you successfully unmarshal this json

P.S. Tested with Gson 2.4

Comment: thanks for your response I have "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $" problem how to fix that error .....

Answer (score 0):

```
Kotlin
```

Late answer and i don't think many face this issue but, i was dealing with a dumb server, that returned the data however it wanted, strange huh?
yes,

```
//response 1
{
"genre":"drama,thriller"
}

//response 2
{
"genre":null
}

//response 3
{
"genre":["drama", "action", "blah", "blah"]
}
```

You can think how unfair this is.

i so changed my genre's data type to `Any?`

like

```
data class Model(...
....
val genre:Any?
...
)
```

now to use it, i do something like this

```
movieInfo.mInfo.genre?.let {
                  if (it is String) {
                     tv_genre.text = it
                  } else if (it is List<*>) {
                     val builder = StringBuilder()
                     it.forEach {
                        if (it is String) {
                           builder.append(it)
                        }
                     }
                     tv_genre.text = builder.toString()
                  }
               }
```